# Large cells in a UICollectionView getting removed while the cell is still displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that contains some large `UICollectionViewCells`.  These cells are so large that they completely fill the `UICollectionView` bounds and extend off screen.

The problem is that the large cells are removed from the `UICollectionView` and queued for reuse while they are still displayed, resulting in a blank view.  If I continue scrolling on the blank `UICollectionView` area, eventually the final portion of the cell appears and the start of the next cell appears in exactly the right place.

I've effectively disabled cell reuse and the problem still occurs apparently because the `UICollectionView` thinks that the cell is no longer displayed since no corner is within the bounds of the collection view.

To demonstrate make a collection view that is a single column and have a cell that is 10000px tall, when scrolling over the very tall cell it will disappear after about 1000px of content is scrolled off the screen and will reappear to display the final 1000px of content for the cell.

You can download a simple prototype app that displays this problem at:  http://jack.cox.s3.amazonaws.com/collectionviewprototype.zip

Comment: I am having the same issue, not sure how to solve it, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I worked around it. The requirements of my app allowed me to just put it all into a single UIScrollView.  I did open a bug report with Apple but have not heard anything back.

Comment: @JackCox the download link isn't working now. Can you put it back up somewhere? Maybe stick it on Github?

Comment: I have filed a radar for this as well, FWIW.

Comment: Same problem here. Any news anyone?

Comment: Since I did further investigations, I posted my own, more detailed question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254222/large-uicollectionviewcell-stopped-being-displayed-when-scrolling

Comment: i posted an hacky answer to @kai question

Comment: Can you guys post the link to the radar so I can dup it?  I'm also having trouble with this.

Comment: I've posted a another possible answer to the other question similar to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254222/large-uicollectionviewcell-stopped-being-displayed-when-scrolling

Comment: I believe this notion of a collection cell that is bigger than the bounds of the view does not sit right with the collection view paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened for me along with this warning in the debug log:

> the behavior of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is not defined because:
>   the item `height` must be less that the height of the `UICollectionView`
>   minus the section `insets` `top` and `bottom` values.

It seems that the out of the box `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` does not support cells larger than the screen.

Comment: How you had fixed this issue @rob.effect

Comment: I solved this by implementing my own layout, which is not limited in cell size. The UICollectionViewFlowLayout is a rather simple layout and does not take long to rewrite.

Comment: If possible Can you @rob.effect share your Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout code ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being tracked as radar #12889164

Comment: Cant find that radar. Got a link?

Comment: @azromej Any chance you could add that to Open Radar? http://openradar.appspot.com/

Comment: @DanyalAytekin I'll do that for future bugs; for this one it seems to be fixed in iOS7

Comment: Thanks, still happens for me with my custom layout though :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix if you are still looking for a quick solution:
When a cell is detected to have a bigger height than the collectionview holding it, the collection view simply needs to be larger than the cell. So set the collecitonView frame to be bigger and correct the content and indicator insets.

```
- (void)updateCollectionViewForLargeCellHeight:(CGFloat)largeCellHeight {
    CGFloat currentCollectionViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.frame);
    if (largeCellHeight > currentCollectionViewHeight) {
        self.collectionViewBottomConstraint = -largeCellHeight; 
        //This is the bottom constraint of the collectionView to its superview. 
        //If you are not using constraints, simply set the frame for the collectionView
        UIEdgeInsets edgeInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, largeCellHeight, 0);
        self.collectionView.contentInset = edgeInset;
        self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInset;
        [self.collectionView needsUpdateConstraints];
    }
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size;
    [self updateCollectionViewForLargeCellHeight:size.height];
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `UICollectionView` with cells of the size of the screen. For iPad the cell size was 768x1024. And haven't found any issues. Please make sure that you have set the `Min Spacing For Cells` and `For Lines` are `0` Also return correct `CGSize` and `UIEdgeInsets` as follows

---

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize retval;
    retval.width=maxWidth; //768 in case of iPad
    retval.height=maxHeight; //1024 in case of iPad
    return retval;
}
```

---

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0 , 0, 0, 0);
}
```