# UICollectionView fall back to UIScrollView

Tags: ios6, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I spent so much time implementing a collection view and subclassed UICollectionViewLayout only to find a bug in iOS 6 which makes cells disappear while scrolling if the cell is very large in size.

[Large UICollectionViewCell's disappearing with custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770484/large-uicollectionviewcells-disappearing-with-custom-layout)

I am unable to find a solution so far, but I realize I may be able to do with just a UIScrollView instead of a UICollectionView and do not need cell reuse. Is there an obvious way to convert existing UICollectionView to a normal UIScrollView ? Of course, I can write my own UIScrollView subclass from scratch but that would mean a lot of work again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using an alternative implementation of UICollectionView called PSTCollectionView :

https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView